# Security permissions for user login

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I am using Firebase only for login purposes (simple email login, Facebook and Twitter). Are there any specific user permissions that I need to set?

Comment: The entire process is described here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html. If you've followed these instructions and are having problems, describe what you've done and what it is that doesn't work.

Comment: I followed it. It worked. The only thing I am asking is whether I need to set any permissions if I am using Firebase only for login services and not storing any data.

Comment: If it works, then apparently you don't need to set any permissions. I'm sorry I can't be more helpful, but it is unclear to me what you're asking. Maybe it helps if you edit your question and indicate *where* you'd set those specific user permissions, e.g. do you mean Firebase's security rules? Or maybe something on your local file system? But then again: if it currently works for you, you might also simply stick to what you've got.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

If understand this correctly, you're using Firebase just for login purposes, nothing else? If so, then my guess is that since you aren't using any data, then read write permissions don't apply.